# d3 How to trigger event on the object behind text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, mouseevent

I draw A `rect` and `text` on svg.

In order to show `text`, I render `rect` first.

I add `mouse click event` to `rect`

when I click the text, it seems the rect is not selected, because rect is behind text, so text is selected frist.

I need to select trigger the event when mouse click inside the `rect`.

How should I do?

Thanks!

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/younyzhU/VmnEC/89/)

You can see, when you mouse click on the text, the rect is not clicked.

```
var data = ["TEXT SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE TEXT SAMPLE"];

var svg = d3.select("svg");
var bar = svg.selectAll("g")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(100,100)"; });

bar.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 50)
    .style("fill", "#f00")
    .on("click", function (d) {
                            alert("text");
                    });
bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("dy", "-.35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the same click handler on the text element?

Comment: Actually, In my case, the text has data(the real problem is much complicated), and every rect has its own data, so when you click function (d) {
                            alert("text");
                    } d is different,  thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can attach a style to the text to ignore mouse events. [Here is the example:](https://jsfiddle.net/VmnEC/91/)

Style:

```
.bar-text {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Modified code:

```
bar.append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 25)
    .attr("class", "bar-text") // add class
    .attr("dy", "-.35em")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Comment: Excellent solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Attach the handler to the `g` element. Complete demo [here](https://jsfiddle.net/VmnEC/90/).

Comment: thanks, actually, in my case the data from text and bar is different. so It is hard to combine into a single group.